# Some Android devices unable to receive notifications through Azure Notification Hub

Tags: android, azure, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have a Xamarin Forms application where we're using Azure Notification Hub to send messages to both Android and iOS devices.

Whenever someone logs into the application a record is created (or updated) for that device. Various information about that device is stored: who it belongs to, installation id, token, etc.

We then call the hub method CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync() for that device's installation. In the case of a new install or cleared data we will be passing in a new installation to Azure Notification Hub to create the installation. In the case of an existing installation we're simply updating the tags so that the correct user will be notified when a message is sent.

This all seems to work as expected. After the call to CreateOrUpdateInstallationAsync() we will see both a Native and a Template registration in the hub for a given installation id. I can log in and out of the application and those device records are updated in the hub. I can see the tags change.

However, for some reason, some Android devices will stop receiving notifications. Sometimes this is immediate. That is, right after the app is installed and the device is registered with the hub, it can't receive messages. Other times it could take up to 24 hours or so, but a device that was receiving messages will suddenly stop.

If I use the Azure Portal to try and directly send a message to the broken Android device it tells me that there are "no matching targets". If I use the Firebase console to send a message to the broken device the message is never received.

iOS never seems to have an issue.

I'm unsure how to proceed. It's almost as if the FCM token is invalid at some point. From what I've read the only time it really should become invalid is if the app is newly installed, the data was cleared, or the device was restored. But this invalidated token seems to happen immediately after install or after a day or so of previously receiving notifications without issue.

If this is the case, is there some way I'm supposed to be aware of this when sending a template message through the hub?

Comment: You could check logcat and see if you successfully registered for the token like https://github.com/CatalystCode/react-native-azurenotificationhub/issues/43#issuecomment-401860960

Comment: I am getting the token. The token is received through my FirebseMessagingService and saved locally and in our database. That token is then used to register the device through AzureNotificationHub, and I can query the hub and see that it's there along with its tags and installationid, etc. It's only later that the Android device will stop receiving notifications. It's almost as if somewhere along the way, as time goes on, the token for Android is no longer valid.

Comment: Do all Android devices have this issue?

Comment: No, not all. It doesn't seem to be limited to any particular OS or device type either. The device will be registered, be able to receive notifications, and then it just ... stops. I can query the hub and see the device there, but if I try and use cURL I get an error saying it's not registered, and if I use the Azure Portal it tells me "no matching targets".

Comment: I thought OnNewToken() would be fired in the Firebase Service when the token changed, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Assuming the token is invalid, the only thing I can think to do at this point is try and get what Firebase considers the current token (outside of OnNewToken) and compare it to what is in the database for that device. If it's different, re-register the device / update the installation to use the new token. This feels like a hack though, because I've seen nothing in any tutorial / documentation / forum to suggest that this is a normal way to handle Android notifications.

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, review your registrations to ensure the tags match when you send a notification. Then, verify the notification receipt from only the clients that have those registrations.
For example, suppose all your registrations with Notification Hubs use the tag "TestA." If you then send a notification with the tag "TestB," the notification won't be sent to any device. A complex case might involve tag expressions where you registered by using "Tag A" or "Tag B," but you targeted "Tag A && Tag B."

Comment: Azure Notification Hubs support FCM through Firebase and iOS/Apple through APNS. Kindly review the app id/key and then re-try (if you haven't done already so)

If your notification doesn't arrive at the client device, review the error might have occurred when Notification Hubs tried to deliver it to the push notification service. In some cases, the payload size might exceed the maximum allowed by the push notification service, or the credentials configured in Notification Hubs might be invalid.

 If feasible, you may test (it can cause throtting) with the EnableTestSend property.

Comment: I have verified the tags are what I expect. Also, I'm only sending to one tag. I know the configurations are correct, because the hub works for other devices. The hub will even work for a specific device and then the next day stop sending to that device. This really does seem to be an issue related to Google invalidating a token and me not being aware that the token is not valid now. I talked to one guy who experienced this issue, and he said they fixed it by using OnNewToken(), checking the token with GetToken() on startup, and having a process scheduled to verify the token once every 12 hrs.

Comment: Which brings me back to my question, documentation would suggest that OnNewToken() is all I need, but that doesn't seem to be the case. It definitely seems like I need to have a backup plan for verifying my token. OnNewToken() is reliable on app install and restores, but it seems like I'm not always being notified the token has changed. Does it make sense to verify the token on app startup? Is that redundant or masking an actual issue? Do I need to go the extra step of verifying a token on a schedule (if the device is plugged in) every few hours to account for times the app is left running?